# How to configure Build braker plugin for sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube

As of now I know sonar has dropped support for Build-braker plugin but I am trying to integrate build breaker plugin for sonarqube. I have 5.6 version of sonarqube and build breaker with 1.1 version installed.In Build breaker plugin I have setup `sonar.buildbreaker.skip to false`. And I run job using Jenkins and maven. for sonarqube analysis I have setup a phase as "prepare-package" where it runs automatically when I do mvn clean install. But, eventhough my quality gate shows failed, my build is still getting success rather than failing. I tried to find documentation but I didn't found better for this. https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Build+Breaker+Plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the Build Breaker on sonarqube 5.1+ if a project quality gate fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885064/how-to-use-the-build-breaker-on-sonarqube-5-1-if-a-project-quality-gate-fails)

Comment: is it a real 'full' sonarqube analysis ? ( -Dsonar.analysis.mode=publish )